# `Reduce` instead of `<<-`

Tags: r, dictionary, reduce

Let's have a function that transforms a list into quasi-JSON string:

```
as.cypher.list = function(l){
  dots = l
  reserved = c("ID", "label")
  properties = dots[!names(dots) %in% reserved]
  properties = gsub("',", "', ",                             # adds spaces after commas
                    gsub('"', "'",                             # replaces " with '
                         gsub('"([^"]+)":', "\\1:",              # removes " around key names
                              toJSON(rapply(properties, as.character)))))
  label = if(is.null(dots[["label"]])) "" else paste0(":", dots[["label"]])
  ID = if(is.null(dots[["ID"]])) NA_character_ else dots[["ID"]]
  query = sprintf("%s%s", label, properties)
  return(query)
}
```

For example:

```
as.cypher.list(list(label="AA", a=1, b="foo", name="bar"))
# [1] ":AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'bar'}"
```

Now let's have:

```
query = "MATCH {n}, {ae} RETURN n"
nodes = list(n=list(label="AA", a=1, b="foo", name="bar"),
             ae=list(label="BB", b=2))
```

How to substitute values from `nodes` list into `query` so that each list name matches the substring inside `query`? The end desirable result after substitution is:

```
query
# [1] "MATCH (n:AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'bar'}), (ae:BB{b:'2'}) RETURN n"
```

I could do it with:

```
add_param = function(nm, val){
  query <<- gsub(paste0("{", nm, "}"), 
                 paste0("(", nm, as.cypher.list(val),")"), 
                 query, fixed = T)
}

Map(add_param, names(nodes), nodes)
# $n
# [1] "MATCH (n:AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'bar'}), {ae} RETURN n"
# 
# $ae
# [1] "MATCH (n:AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'vser'}), (ae:BB{b:'2'}) RETURN n"
```

However notice the use of `<<-` which is quite awkward.

How to a use `Reduce()` in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just write a `for` loop? seems much easier

Comment: Wanted to learn MapReduce style. Also, for loops should be avoided.

Comment: The bad use of for loops should definitely be avoided. In your case a for loop is fine because you would be just looping over `seq_along(nodes)` and only updating the variable `query` within the loop, so perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only slight problem here is that when you use `Reduce` over a named list, you don't have access to the names in the function. One way around around that is to just embed the names with the data. You can do a transformation like `Map(list, names(nodes), nodes)`. Then once you have this object you can iteratete over that has all the information you need, you can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(q,n) {
    nm <- n[[1]]
    val <- n[[2]]
    gsub(paste0("{", nm, "}"), 
        paste0("(", nm, as.cypher.list(val),")"), 
        q, fixed = T)
}, Map(list, names(nodes), nodes), init=query)
# [1] "MATCH (n:AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'bar'}), (ae:BB{b:'2'}) RETURN n"
```

You could also consider doing the extraction/replacement with `regmatches()`. Here's one such strategy

```
tnodes <- mapply(function(nm, val) paste0("(", nm, as.cypher.list(val),")"), 
    names(nodes), nodes)
query <- "MATCH {n}, {ae} RETURN n"
m <- gregexpr("\\{[^}]+\\}", query)
regmatches(query, m) <- lapply(regmatches(query, m), function(x) {
    names <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x)-1)
    tnodes[names]
})
query
# [1] "MATCH (n:AA{a:'1', b:'foo', name:'bar'}), (ae:BB{b:'2'}) RETURN n"
```

Basically we first cache the transformed values of the nodes, then look for all '{xx}' tokens and replace them with the corresponding values.

Comment: Thank you so so much! In the `regmatches` approach, aren't the braces mixed up and instead: `m <- gregexpr("\\{[^]}+\\}", query)` ?

Comment: @DanielKrizian No. They are correct in the answer as I wrote it. Basically the character class match is everything but the end-brace.